# Add Shape created by .intersect to a Canvas?

Tags: javafx, coordinates, shapes, geometry

I am trying to highlight an Area that gets intersected by 2 Circle:

Example 1.:
The Yellow dots get, for testing purposes, random values. Those are used to draw a circle around, as well as to store an ellipse in the Background. In the Case of no intersection, the GUI acts correctly and display this:
[image: The Purple outline represents the circle]

After the random Values, the Shapes intersect. As I cannot seem to be able to add the new Shape made trough .intersect(), I just did a quick sp.setContent(), and got this image:[image]

This basicly shows me the intersected space and colors it blue.

Everything is drawn on a Canvas, which basicly does the following:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(250, 250);
....
gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
canvas.setHeight(imgTemp.getHeight());
canvas.setWidth(imgTemp.getWidth());
gc.drawImage(imgTemp, 0, 0);
```

Aswell as with some other Loops to draw the shapes and the circles.
Now, the code for the intersect is the following:

```
if (!(e.equals(eT))) {
    if (e.getBoundsInParent().intersects(eT.getBoundsInParent())) {
    System.out.println("Collision detected!");
    Shape inter = Shape.intersect(e, eT);
    if(inter.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() > 0 && 0 < inter.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()){
    inter.setFill(BLUE);
    inter.setStrokeWidth(3);
    sp.setContent(inter);
    }
 }
```

I'm not that used to JavaFX and have only begun really working on it this Weekend for a small Project, but I am guessing that I might need to change from canvas to something else to make use of the shapes? Or is there a way to "tranform" the Shape of the intersect into something drawable by GraphicsContext2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just put your Canvas into a Group and then add your shapes to the same Group. Why would you insist on drawing everything into the Canvas? A Canvas is just a Node like all the other Shapes and you can mix them freely in the SceneGraph.

Another question would be why you are using the Canvas at all if you have already realized that this leads to problems in your case.

Comment: Ive just realised it when trying to get the .intersect(). But this means that I dont need the Canvas at all and can just use Group.add() for the shapes?

Comment: Sure, that is what the scene graph is made for. Of course you have to attach the Group to the scene graph and make sure that the surrounding Pane does not interfere with your placement of the graphics.

Comment: Everything works, but somehow the .intersects get placed at the wrong place. Somehow they are not in the correct spot. Im gona assume that is because Im putting the Group in a Scrollpane? Currently Im doing group.getChildren().add(canvas) (which has an image), .addAll(shapes), and sp.setcontent(group). This is the result:

http://imgur.com/uC4d6Op

Comment: Difficult to tell what the exact problem is without beeing able to try the whole code. It's probably an inconsistent use of coordinate systems or some issue with the Scrollpane.